# Filtering order list in ofbiz for a store

Tags: installation, ofbiz

We have created multiple stores in single ofbiz instance. We need to populate order list for a given admin user for a store. Currently its showing orders of both the stores even though user is not a part of second store.
Please suggest if it is possible. If yes, please let me know the corresponding configuration/code changes required.

Answer (score 1):

You simply can filter the orders by the productStoreId which is part of the OrderHeader entity, see http://demo-stable-ofbiz.apache.org/webtools/control/FindGeneric?entityName=OrderHeader .